# Picture with float right is jumping while resizing of container

Tags: jquery, css, width

I got a website here: http://jaco.zz.mu/ and when you choose about me, and then games to show games menu, for the moment when $(...).animate({width: ...}, 200) is doing the resizing the right scrollbar is gone (only during the resizing caused by toggling games menu by clicking games and because of that my portrait on the right of the about me page which has style float: right, gets messed up for a moment,

what I'd like to do:

1.keep the scrollbar even during jquery animate changing widths

or

2.suggestions how to keep the image in the same place all the time not jumping like now

I'm using chrome but I think the same bug is repeatable in any browser,

the whole css is in one file when you'll check the source you'll see, same with js

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are experiencing is not to do with the floated image nor the browser.
You have double scroll bars on the about us page because content for #frame has scroll as well as the the page.

If you shrink your browser window height you will see the double scroll bar problem.

removing overflow-y from #main should fix this but may cause other problem due to the way the page has been created.

Comment: dude thanks for your time but the overflow-y: auto (scrollbar) is in there for a purpouse.
My question is, why does the scrollbar of #main div disappear during jquery animate ???